# Replace Extra Words

Tags: regex, text, replace, editor, atom-editor

I am trying to see if there is a shortcut around doing ~300 lines of backspacing because I am trying to get all the libraries from the [Python Standard Library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/) and put it into a `.txt` or `.js` file. For example, if I were to get the `string — Common string operations` library, then I would have to remove `— Common string operations`. Fortunately, there is the hyphen to function as a starting point for the regex. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I would like to explain myself if there is not enough information, or make a correction if there is one to be made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the next regular expression you can capture the first part in $1 capture group and in $2 everything you want to remove.

**(\w*) \— ((\w*)\s)***

Consider in atom replacing for $1 to only get the first part.
Notice "-" != "—"
[https://regexr.com/4v2e9](http://regexr.com/4v2e9)

Comment: I just needed to add \n at the end after "\s" for it to work, but other than that it works great :) `(\w*) \— ((\w*)\s\n)*`